# How to limit a user to add max 6 products of each category in cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to limit a user to add **max 6 products** of **each category in cart** in WooCommerce.

I am using the following code but unfortunately without success

```php
// Checking and validating when updating cart item quantities when products are added to cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_validation', 'only_six_items_allowed_cart_update', 10, 4 );
function only_six_items_allowed_cart_update( $passed, $cart_item_key, $values, $updated_quantity ) {

    $cart_items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $original_quantity = $values['quantity'];
    $total_count = $cart_items_count - $original_quantity + $updated_quantity;

    if( $cart_items_count > 6 || $total_count > 6 ){
        // Set to false
        $passed = false;
        // Display a message
         wc_add_notice( __( "You can’t have more than 6 items in cart", "woocommerce" ), "error" );
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

Comment: For clarity: you want to limit products to 6 pieces, where the products belong to the same product category? Or just a limit of 6 pieces per product?

Answer (score 0):

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) { 
    if ( $quantity>6 )) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'You are not allowed to add more than 6 product for category..', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        $passed = false;
    }
    return $passed; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_validation', 10, 3 );
```